# AngularJS showing value based on id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How can I change data based on id that is passed from json file.
JSON:

```
{
  "hotels": [
  {
     "id" : 1,
     "name": "some hotel 1",
     "category" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "hotel_id" : 1,
         "name"  : "Cat name 1",
         "bnb" : "yes",
         "simple" : "yes"
     }]
  },
   {
     "id" : 2,
     "name": "some hotel 2",
     "category" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "hotel_id" : 2,
         "name"  : "Cat name 1",
         "bnb" : "yes",
         "simple" : "yes"
     }]
  }
  ]
}
```

in my html I have ng-repeat like:

```
<p>Hotel names</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="hotel in list.hotels">

            {{hotel.name}}

            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <p>Category</p>
                <li ng-repeat="cat in hotel.category">
                    {{cat.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So this will show all what I have in that json file and I'm trying to limit it to show only data for one hotel (I know that I can do it with something like `{{hotel[0].name}}`) but there must be better approach, and also how can I use some kind of a switch by pressing the button to show data from hotel with id 1 to hotel with id 2 in the same div and vice versa?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using an `ng-repeat` if you only want to display one?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please update it. You want to show only 1 item based on what condition?

Comment: Your `hotel` object has an array of `category`, but not a `categories` property. Shouldn't your second `ng-repeat` be: `<li ng-repeat="cat in hotel.category">{{cat.name}}</li>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ng-repeat` to create the links to display the hotel based on the click like in the following demo or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/f8acxpna/).

For the categories you can use another `ng-repeat` (not added in the demo).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('mainController', MainController);
  
function MainController() {
 
  this.hotels = [
  {
     "id" : 1,
     "name": "some hotel 1",
     "category" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "hotel_id" : 1,
         "name"  : "Cat name 1",
         "bnb" : "yes",
         "simple" : "yes"
     }]
  },
   {
     "id" : 2,
     "name": "some hotel 2",
     "category" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "hotel_id" : 2,
         "name"  : "Cat name 1",
         "bnb" : "yes",
         "simple" : "yes"
     }]
  }
  ];
 this.selectedHotel = this.hotels[0];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
  
  <a href="#" ng-repeat="hotel in mainCtrl.hotels" ng-click="mainCtrl.selectedHotel = hotel">{{hotel.name}}</a>
  
  <div>
    Hotel name: {{mainCtrl.selectedHotel.name}}
    Category: {{mainCtrl.selectedHotel.category}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, but since I am passing this from a file, what should I change to achieve this?

Comment: You can get the data with an ajax request like in this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/f8acxpna/1/). You need to host that file with a webserver to have it work. Then you could do something like `$http.get('http://localhost/hotels.json').then(...)` or create a backend route that's returning the json file for you.

Comment: I get the error for undefined hotelService. This is my structure: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRhDrYdTJYMcfkq3K4WD?p=preview I get error in console Error: hotelService is not defined What should I change?

Comment: Here is an updated [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/ME7nWoyXHO6PtumYyY06?p=preview). Changed filter to a service and updated angular src. You had Angular 1.0.x and that doesn't support `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why am I getting now Error: json[0] is undefined but I guess I have spelling mistake somewhere.... Even after double checking, I am still not able to see it...

Comment: You're welcome. I think you can remove the `[0]` if there are no outer brackets `[]` in your json file and I think it's OK to have the json file just start with curly braces.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, notice ng-if added

```
<p>Hotel names</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="hotel in list.hotels">

        {{hotel.name}}

        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <p>Category</p>
            <li ng-repeat="cat in hotel.categories" ng-if="cat.id == yourid">
                {{cat.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can change yourid by using the current controller. And as other people suggest, you shouldn't use ng-repeat if you want to display only one element

Comment: Thank you, can you also tell me how can I add that switch for example, I have 2 buttons and data is showed by pressing one of them, so when button 1 is pressed, data for hotel 1 is showed, when button 2 is pressed data for hotel 2 is showed.

Comment: It would still work if you apply ng-if on the hotel list repeat
    <li ng-repeat="hotel in list.hotels" ng-if="condition">
so say you bind a ng-click on the button which with change the condition from "show data1" to "show data2", and $apply, it would behave as you wish
Cheer!